# 404 in Controller Action Method : Laravel 5.2.37

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have following Controller Action Method.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\SportsType;
class SportsTypeApiController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function apiSportsTypes() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Here is the route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::get('/apiSportsTypes', 'API\SportsType\SportsTypeApiController@apiSportsTypes');
});
```

It gives 404 error. Am I missing something? Please let me know if you need more details.

[image]

Comment: you should better show the namespace you defined in your SportsTypeApiController, furthermore, why do you keep public uri?

Comment: I added the namespace.

Comment: How about your server configuration or how do you serve your application and asking again but, why do you  use the `public` uri to access that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was happening because the routes were using cache. Due to that new routes were not even appearing in command prompt even if I was typing below command.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Then I had to remove the route cache by using the below command

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and now everything is working fine.